# finding a maximum value in arrays using channel (go routines) but facing a deadlock

Tags: go, channel, goroutine

I'm creating a function with go routines and channels, that can accept arrays for any size for example `{100,122, 14, 64, ...}` and it will find the higher value of deduction between the array from the last position and the previous position and so on. So for example 64 is greater than 14 then it must be deducted and you'll get the higher value but it wont deduct with the value that higher than the current one.
Currently I'm facing a deadlock, and do not know how to fix it

```
func maximumValue(b ...int){
    maxValue := make(chan int)
    maxInteger := 0

    for i := len(b)-1; i >0 ;i--{
        go getHigher(b, b[i],maxValue)
    }

    for n := range maxValue {
        if n > maxInteger{
            maxInteger = n
        }
    }

    fmt.Println(maxInteger)
}

func getHigher(b []int, x int, maxValue chan<- int) {
    higherValue := 0
    for _, v:=range b{
        if x>v && higherValue < x-v {
            higherValue = x-v
        }
    }
    maxValue <- higherValue
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For-loop over a channel will continue to read from that channel while it is open. Since your program does not close the channel, it deadlocks as soon as all goroutines writing to the channel terminate.

Use a `sync.WaitGroup` for your goroutines, and close the channel once all goroutines are completed:

```
var wg sync.WaitGroup
for i := len(b)-1; i >0 ;i--{
        wg.Add(1)
        go getHigher(b, b[i],maxValue,&wg)
}
go func() {
  wg.Wait()
  close(maxValue)
}()

for n := range maxValue {
   if n > maxInteger{
       maxInteger = n
  }
}

func getHigher(b []int, x int, maxValue chan<- int,wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
   defer wg.Done()
   ...
}
```